# Migrate existing instance to new network

Tags: networking, google-compute-engine, gcloud, gcloud-cli

In one of my GCP projects, I have created a new network with heightened security settings compared to the default network created for any project.  I would like to migrate my existing instances from the default network to this new network without deleting them.

I'm under the impression that this can be accomplished by removing the existing access config, and then adding a new one that will be associated with the new network.  So:
`gcloud compute delete-access-config <name of instance> access-config-name=<name of config>` followed by `gcloud compute add-access-config <name of instance> access-config-name=<name of new config>`.  However, this only seems to affect the external IP of the instance and not the network itself.  How would I go about removing the instance from the default network and moving it to the new one?

Answer (score 0):

The helptext for these commands do not have a "name" flag. Did you mean to say "--access-config-name?:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/add-access-config
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/delete-access-config